# Java/Hibernate: How to detect, if field is lazy-loaded proxy and not actual data?

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading, dto

I'm converting my entity to DTO and I want to set NULL as DTO value for all fields, which are lazy-loaded and not initialized (because I do not want to transfer all the data all the time).

I've tried:

```
if (!(entity.getNationality() instanceof HibernateProxy))
    this.setNationalityFromEntity(entity.getNationality());
```

But it did not seemed to help.
Any suggestions are welcome!

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

The class is always a proxy, whether it's initialized or not, so you're going to exclude it every time if you just check for instances of proxy.  The Lazy Load does not cause the Proxy reference on the entity to be replaced with a reference to a new object, it just populates the fields.

To find out if it's actually initialized you need to ask it!

```
if (HibernateProxy.class.isInstance(entity.getNationality())) {
  HibernateProxy proxy = HibernateProxy.class.cast(entity.getNationality());
  if (!proxy.getHibernateLazyInitializer().isUninitialized()) {
    this.setNationalityFromEntity(entity.getNationality());
  }
}
```

Comment: This is basically what `Hibernate.isInitialized(..)` does, but in greater extend. But yes, it pointed me to the right direction and by further investigating the lazy instances, I've found out, that the entity MUST NOT be in the open session to correctly signalize the initialization state. The simplest solution I've found was to call `Session.evict(..)` and then, `Hibernate.isInitialized()` works as expected.

Answer (score 5):

They way we do this in our Entities is we have boolean methods which do the check in a way that will not trigger the lazy loading. For example, if our Entity had an associated entity called 'associatedSomething', then the method to check if that associated Entity has been lazy loaded would be:

```
    public boolean isAssociatedSomethingLoaded() {
        if (associatedSomething instanceof HibernateProxy) {
            if (((HibernateProxy)associatedSomething).getHibernateLazyInitializer().isUninitialized()) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return (getAssociatedSomething() != null);
    }
```

NOTE: It's important not to use `getAssociatedSomething()` in the check, as this makes sure that the associated Entity does not get lazy-loaded during the check.

Answer (score 1):

The mere possibility of being able to invoke a getter for some state that shouldn't be available for a use case is problematic in my opinion, but that's a different story. I would suggest you implement a proper DTO approach instead to avoid accidental errors.

I created [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage) for exactly that use case. You essentially define DTOs for JPA entities as interfaces and apply them on a query. It supports mapping nested DTOs, collection etc., essentially everything you'd expect and on top of that, it will improve your query performance as it will generate queries fetching just the data that you actually require for the DTOs.

The entity views for your example could look like this

```
@EntityView(Person.class)
interface PersonDto {
  String getNationality();
}
```

Querying could look like this

```
List<PersonDto> dtos = entityViewManager.applySetting(
  EntityViewSetting.create(PersonDto.class),
  criteriaBuilderFactory.create(em, Person.class)
).getResultList();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a built in Hibernate method for this.

```java
// Assume that 'myObject' is an instance of a Hibernate proxy
if (Hibernate.isInitialized(myObject)) {
    // The proxy has been initialized, we can safely access its properties
    // ...
} else {
    // The proxy has not been initialized yet, we should load it before accessing its properties
    // ...
}
```